# how to use md5sum on certain files

Tags: bash, unix, shell, md5

Imagine I have a filelist like this:

```
file1.php
file2.php
login1.php
login2.php
logout1.php
logout2.php
```

And I want to do an `md5sum` on files called `login*` <- something like that. I need to count md5 of all files starting with `login`, continuing with whatever.

How do I do this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
md5sum login*
```

If that doesn't work, you're trying to take the md5sum of files that don't even exist.

Comment: ``md5sum: login*: No such file or directory``

Comment: Then you're trying to take the md5sum of files *that don't even exist*.

Comment: Uhm I feel so stupid, I have no idea why this didn't work before, but I'd swear I tried this at some point. Well, thanks, it works ..